# Load external properties with Sping location property with relative path

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I wan to divide my `application.properties` to constant ones inside and compliled with a `.jar` and the second one which will hold "per server" and runtime changed values out of the `.jar` in another directory.

I would like to have in example sucha structure:

```
|
|-configFolder
|  |_application.properties
|
|_projectFolder
  |_app.jar
```

what I want to achieve is to point spring config location with relative path into that `configFolder` to load config files.
I tried to:

```
spring:
  config:
    location: file:./../configFolder
```

but it didn't worked for me.

Do you know if relative paths are possible to use in that place? I would not use absolute directory while I could deploy code on different servers, so relative paths are convenient for me.

Comment: What values, particularly, are you wanting to put inside your jar, and why?

Comment: For example: db port, db password and user, email credentials to send emails from applications. I would like to keep my code and built jar generic and depends on where I deploy that (production server/testing server/ another server) I want to set different configurations.
Maybe in the future I would have some algorithm parameters in property file depends on particular server need (time of automatic email send etc.)

Comment: Those are _exactly the items_ that should not be packaged into an application. Set those at runtime using appropriate environment variables.

Comment: Could you provide any example? I want to dockerize the application so I would need to provide those information in some way. I can use docker-compose and set those variables in compose file, or (don't want to do- tedious run command) pass them during docker RUN command as env variables- somehow it leaves marks in terminal history... I need to store that information somewhere. 
Anyway in my post I don't go into details what I want to keep in that file but just ask if that's possible because I couldn't find any example to do it.